# AngularJS - Scope data not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been retrieving data and displaying it throughout my project using basically the same code steps, but suddenly I have a situation where my "$scope" data from one function is not displaying in my HTML page.  The data is there, and the field names are exactly as they appear in the returned data, but for whatever reason it will not display.  I'm using bootstrap tabs, and this data is supposed to show on the 2nd tab.  I thought perhaps the problem might be in the HTML on the tab so I MOVED the "{{data.whatever}}" to a tab whose data was displaying correctly just to see if that was the issue, and it still didn't display.

The picture below shows what I am getting back in my controller:

[image]

However when I try to render the data in my code as follows:

```
<tr style="background-color:#cfe7f1">
                                    <th>SSQ Last Edited By</th>
                                    <th>Date Edited</th>
                                    <th>Last Incident QTR Reported</th>
                                    <th>Number of Employees</th>
                                    <th>Number of Active Instructors</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Jim Sanders</td>
                                    <td>07/15/2015</td>
                                    <td>{{ssqdetails.vchLastCompleteQuarter}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ssqdetails.intAvgNumEmployees}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ssqdetails.ActiveInstructorCount}}</td>
                                </tr>
```

I have another table very much like the one above that uses a similar call and the data displays perfectly.  This has me completely baffled.  If anyone has any ideas, please share.  I didn't show the ENTIRE HTML, controller, or app code for brevity, but if you need more information in order to help, just let me know, and I will include whatever may help.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems that `newdata` is wrapped in an array. Try `$scope.ssqdetails = newdata[0][0]`.

Comment: sometimes helps to throw `<pre>{{ssqdetails |json}}</pre>` in view for quick reference. You really need to inspect scope within the view using dev tools...not just at controller .

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos - the ARRAY was EXACTLY the problem.  Once I put an ng-repeat detail in ssqdetails, the data displayed perfectly.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you posted it appears that the object is wrapped in an array.

Setting `$scope.ssqdetails = newdata[0];` should do the trick as a dirty fix, but it is better to adjust the response of the service, so as to returns an object.

Comment: I'm not sure how to adjust the response of the service so that it returns as an object, but I will try to find something online to tell me how to do that.  The ng-repeat did make the data display.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I tried to use your suggestion above $scope.ssqdetails = newdata[0][0]; but the data still does not display.  It only displays with the ng-repeat.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, did you also tried `$scope.ssqdetails = newdata[0];`?

Comment: Yes, lol.  I was just coming back to tell you that removing the second [0] worked.  Thanks again!  Have a great day!

Comment: Glad it helped. Wasn't sure if it's one or two levels down, as the `[[object Object]]` notation of the IDE (I guess it's Visual Studio) was confusing me:)

Comment: As for adjusting the response of service, it depends. In the case of the question the array contains only one object. But if the service potentially returns a collection of objects, therefore the array structure / the `ng-repeat` is justified.